# Angular/Ionic CORS Policy

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, cors

i tried to fix this problem using the server proxy

```
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "type": "angular",
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/api",
      "proxyUrl": "my_url"
    }
  ]
}
```

then i replaced in my enviroment fodler my variable baseUrl: '/api'

it not work, where i mistake?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CORS should be enabled on the server-side by sending `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header with a proper value. So in most cases you have nothing to do with it on the client-side (Angular/Ionic).

For example if you're trying to access API resource served on `GET https://example.com/api/users`, the endpoint among other headers should return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as well.

More about CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

How to enable it: https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: thank so much, i fix it!! Now the app work on browser but if i deploy on android it not work, the list that would be download there isn't, the view is empty